# how to type the degree sign (°) using Chinese IME on iOS/(mac)OS?

Tags: writing

[Some people](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/180271228.html) say you can

> 打“摄氏度”

to get: `℃` but that seems to be a sogou IME thing only - and boy does that celsius degrees C look ugly.

[Others suggest](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/180271228.html):

> “插入”“特殊符号”

but that just seems to be a Word thing.

Any idea how to do this, easily, on ios and mac os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shift-Option-8` produces ° on my UK Mac simplified Chinese pinyin input keyboard. I don't have experience with the standard iOS chinese keyboard, but on the chinese Google gBoard you can hold down 0 to get °. Caveat- I'm not sure if these symbols are precisely degree symbols.

Comment: (just commenting that this works on the stock iOS keyboard as well)

Answer (score 1):

i "fixed" my input method as "unicode hex input" on my macbook, so, to type celsius symbol, just press "option" + "2" + "1" + "0" + "3"; the **℃** would appear immediately :)

imo, it's convenience; provided you know the code point.